# How to change label.text in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to change a label text from cs file after I receive a message from the server. 
I tried using to put the label in updatepanel but couldn't make it work.
How can i update the display of the label?

Comment: Please clarify your question, or it'll get downvoted (not to mention it won't be answered). What triggers this message from the server? Are you just trying to update text from codebehind?

Comment: Hi Welcome to Stackoverflow please read this [About](http://stackoverflow.com/about) before post or answer any question.

Comment: i'm trying to update from codebehind. I have a server that i wrote and i use wcf to send msgs to the client. The trigger can be different things, I have a method that handles the event when the client receive a message. in this method i'm trying to change the label but i can't find a way to update the display after the change.

Comment: Remember, from your server's point of view, a web page is a response to an http request. It builds a response, sends it to the browser, and then _the page class is destroyed_, only to be rebuilt from the scratch at the next request for just long enough to generate another response. If you have a thread somewhere receiving messages separately from your web app, at the time those messages arrive your page class instance doesn't exist.

Comment: Following @JoelCoehoorn ideia maybe you are looking for a server side event.
With those anything that happens in the server can be "pushed" into client browsers without the need for them to request the server (either to post or get data from it).
This way the browser will wait for the requests to come from the server and do something (in your case update a label using javasccript) whenever it happens.
My2c

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to avoid a post back, then you can use ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods to query the server via AJAX and then push the value returned into the label control, like this:

Markup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.TheButton').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/GetDate",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('.TheLabel').text(data.d);
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Nothing" CssClass="TheLabel" />
<br/>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" CssClass="TheButton" Text="Update Label"/>
```

Code-behind:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetDate()
{
    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Note: ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods are `static` methods that are not part of the ASP.NET page life-cycle. They do not have access to any of the controls on the page, but are very useful for getting data from the server (in this case the server time). In the interest of simplicity, I used CSS class names on the server controls to make the jQuery selectors simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is something along the lines of

```
myLabel.Text = "Value";
```

If it's in an UpdatePanel, the rules are a little different. I think you need to get the control, then update its value. Something along the lines of:

```
Label lbl = (Label) updatePanel1.FindControl("myLabel");
lbl.Text = "Value";
```

Comment: It get hit but the display stays the same

Comment: If you use the IE Developer Tools, FireBug or Chrome HTML debugging tools, do you see a value in there? (Maybe it's visible but broken HTML is preventing you from seeing it)